# How to make variable not change? after doing a function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

so i want to calculate score for my quiz result, i get the answer from my answer table in database and calculate it in **score()** function inside controller.

i want to make difference between calculate quiz result in first try and second, so if my result in quiz 1 was 20 then my second try will not be 20+second try score.

i do that by adding column disable to answer table, and the default value when anwers added is false,the anwer data will be calculate is data with disable column with false value,  and after calculate in function score() i turn the disable column to be true with **update()** function. in controller.

the problem is disable column always true so my score() function can't calculate the answers data

my code in controller
function to get score data:

```
public function getShowResultOfQuiz($id){
    $categoryquiz= JenisQuiz::find($id);
    $user=Auth::user()->id;
    $score=$this->score(); //go to score function
    $kelas = Auth::user()->kelas;
    $instansi = Auth::user()->instansi;

    History::create([
        'user_id'=>$user,
        'jenis_quiz_id'=>$id,
        'score'=> $score,
        'kelas' => $kelas,
        'instansi' => $instansi
        ]); //create data score in database

    $this->update(); //goto update function

    switch ($id) {
        case '1':
        return view('user.pages.quizresult',compact('score','categoryquiz','sarans','answers'));

        break;

        case '2':
        return view('user.pages.quizanxietyresult',compact('score','categoryquiz','answers','sarans'));
        break;

        case '3':
        return view('user.pages.quizdepresiresult',compact('score','categoryquiz','$answers','$sarans'));
        break;
    }

}
```

function to calculate score :

```
public function score(){
    $user_data = Auth::user();
    $answers = $user_data->answer()->select('user_answer')->where('disable','=',false)->get(); // get answer data with only if disable value false
    $a = 0;
    $b = 0;
    $c = 0;
    if($answers->count()) {
        foreach ($answers as $answer) {
            switch ($answer->user_answer) {
                case 1:
                $a++;
                break;
                case 2:
                $b++;
                break;
                case 3:
                $c++;   
                break;
            }
        }

    }
    return $a+$b+$c; //return $score
}
```

my update function :

```
public function update(){
    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $user_data = User::find($user_id);
    $answers_update = $user_data->answer()->whereDisable(false);
    $answers_update->update(array("disable" => true)); //turn disable value to true
}
```

expect : call data answer with disable value false -> calculate it in score function -> save score in database-> turn disable data value = true

problem :  turn data disable true -> answer data can't get by score function

Comment: Why aren't you doing something like `$answers = $user_data->answer()->select('user_answer')->whereDisable(false)->get();`?

Comment: to get the answer data from user logged, and get the data where disable = false to calculate the score only for the false one... 
so when i input answer again (when i input the disable columnn value default was false) its only get the false one , not the true one... sorry i'm not good at described it

Comment: aren't that same as where("disable",'=',false)?